# Mixed formatted List/String from Serial

Tags: python, string, list, usb, text-formatting

i am new to python. I have some experience with Pascal and a little bit with C++.
At the moment i have to program some code for a research project demonstrator. 
The setup is as follows:

We have a 868MHz radio master device. i can communicate with this device via a USB port (COM4 at the moment but may change in the future). 
The 868MHz master communicates with a slave unit. The slave unit replies with a message that i can read from the USB port.

Until this point everything works good. I request data packages and also receive them.
From the moment of receiving the data packages i have a propblem i seem not 
able to solve on myself.

I use Anaconda 32 bit with the Spyder editor

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May  7 13:35:59 2015

@author: roland
"""

import serial


portnr = 3        #Serial Port Number 0=Com1, 3=Com4
portbaud = 38400  #Baud rate
tiout = 0.1         #Timout in seconds
i = 1

wrword = ([0x02,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x71,0xF8])   

try:
    ser = serial.Serial(portnr, portbaud, timeout=tiout)  # open port
except:
    ser.close()             # close port
    ser = serial.Serial(portnr, portbaud, timeout=tiout)  # open port

print(ser.name)          # check which port was really used
while (i < 100):
    ser.write(wrword)
    seread = ser.readline()
    print(seread)
    i = i+1
    sere = seread.split()
    try:
        readdat = str(sere[0])
    except:
        print("Index Error")
    retlen = len(readdat)
    print(retlen)
    readdat = readdat[2:retlen-1]
    print(readdat)


ser.close()             # close port
```

The variable wrword is my request to the 868MHz radio master.
The Format is as follows:

0x02  Address of the unit

0x04  Command to send information from a certain register range

0x00 0x00 Address of first Register (Start address 0 is valid!)

0x00 0x02 Information how much registers are to be sent (in this case Registers 0 and 1 shall be transmitted to the Radio master)

0x71 0xF8 Checksum of the command sentence.

The program sends the command sequence successful to the master unit and the slave unit answers. Each time the command is send an answer is expected. Nevertheless it may happen that now correct answer is given thats why the 
try command is in use.
I know i use ser.readline() but this is sufficient for the application.

I receive a list as answer from the USB Port.
The data look as follows:

b'\x02\x04\x04\x12\xb6\x12\xa5\xe0\xc1' (This is the Output from print(seread) )

For clarification this answer is correct and must be read as follows:

\x02   Address of the answering unit
\x04   Function that was executed (Read from certain register area)
\x04   Number of Bytes of the answer
\x12 \xb6   Value of first register (2 Byte)
\x12 \xa5   Value of second register (2 Byte)
\xe0 \xc1   Checksum of answer

If the data from the com port had all this Format i might be able to get the data values from the both Registers. But unfortunately the data format is not always the same.

Sometimes i receive answers in the following style:

b'\x02\x04\x04\x12\x8e\x12{\xe1T'

The answer is similar to the example above (different values in the Registers and different checksum) but the Format i receive has changed.

If i use the hex ASCII codes for the symbols obviously not hex values i find a valid answer telegram.

b'\x02\x04\x04\x12\x8e\x12{\xe1T'

becomes

b'\x02\x04\x04\x12\x8e\x12\x7b\xe1\x54'

when i Exchange the ASCII symbols by their hex code by Hand.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to force Python to give me the answer in a defined Format?
2. If not is it possible to handle the list or the string i can derive from the list in such a way that i get my values in the required format?
3. Does somebody can give me a hint how to extract my register values from the list and convert the two hex numbers of each register into one integer value for each register (the first value is the high byte, the second the low byte)?

Thanks in advance for your answer(s)

sincerely

Roland

Comment: by " force Python to give me the answer in a defined Format" do you mean you want  to  print the value of readdat  in hex ?

Comment: In principle i don't care what Format i get as Long as it is consistent (ALL Hex or ALL ASCII or ALL Binary) I Need to get the vaklues in the Registers and to calculate values from it.    Unfortunately i can not think of a way to seperate this mixed formatted data so i can always get the values in the Registers :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
During a small testpiece of program i stumbled upon the fact that the variable ***seread*** contains already the data in a suitable and usable format for me.

I assume that the Spyder Editor causes the format change when displaying byte type objects. 
If i Access the single Bytes using seread[i] while i is in range 0 to len(seread)-1 i receive the correct values for the single bytes.

So i can acess my data and calculate my measurement values as required.

Nevertheless thanks to **keety** for reading my question.